# Users with the highest number of hats, per site

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

How can I see the users who earned the highest number of hats until now **on a per-site basis**?

The maximum I saw was 19 (earned by two users) but I don't think this is the actual highest one.

Comment: why the downvote ? did I said something wrong ?

Comment: On first glance, it's too trivial since people think you refer to the raw amount, network wide which is visible in the Network Leaderboard. But if you ask for comparison of per-site hat leaders (see my comment on the answer), then it can become complicated. If you'll edit the question to focus on this, it might start getting upvotes.

Comment: I've got 25 on SciFi, so 19 definitely isn't the highest.

Answer (score 6):

Just look at the leaderboard..

http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard

At the time of writing, the leader has a total of 31 hats from all sites.
Scrolling down the list gives you the leading number of hats on each site.

Comment: The answer is not complete, since there are per-site hats. The 31 is for the top user in the whole Network, i.e. having 31 distinct hats in the whole network. However, that same user has "only" 24 hats on his "main site", as can be seen [here](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/codereview.stackexchange.com). In this regard, [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) is leading in the per-site collection by having 28 hats in single site. (Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 4):

For a detailed view on the per-site leaderboard, visit

```
http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/<site>
```

where `<site>` is the site you're after, like `askubuntu.com`, or `stackoverflow.com`, ...

---

The [Winterbash leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) ranks the per-site leaderboard in decreasing order. At the top is the entire network, with sites ranked top-to-bottom below it:

[image]

From the above picture we can see that [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) leads the network-wide race for hats at around 77k, followed by [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com) with around 12k. We also see a per-site leaderboard listed on the right of each site, again in descending order. For example, [Seth](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth) on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) is currently one of maddest hatters having most of the 7k hats on that site.

Clicking on the site in the left-most column provides the per-site leaderboard. Here's [the leaderboard for Ask Ubuntu](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/askubuntu.com) showing Seth *sharing* the pole position:

[image]

To the right is listed 9 of the hats currently owned by each user. If you want to see all the hats owned by any specific user, click on their profile image and on their "hats link":

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the site-wide leaderboard may have a slight lag in being updated compared to the user-specific profile.